# flutter даёт ошибку, нет контента на странице

Tags: flutter, dart

При запуске этого кода происходит ошибка, буду очень благодарен тому, кто поможет

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(ChooseDomain());

}
String name = ".md";
int x = 0;
String valute = "MDL";
int y = 0;
String tick = "❌";
class ChooseDomain extends StatelessWidget {

  void restart() => runApp(ChooseDomain());
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
   return MaterialApp(

     home: Scaffold(
         appBar: AppBar(
             title: const Text('Выберите домен'),
           backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
         ),
       body: Column(
           children: <Widget>[
             Container(
               color: Colors.grey,
               child: Row(
                 children: <Widget>[
                   TextButton(
                       child: Text('$tick Зарегистрировать новый домен'),
                    onPressed:(){
                         tick = "✅";
                         restart();
                    }
                   ),
             TextButton(
               child: const Text('www.'),
               onPressed: () {
                 String a = "NONE";
               }
             ),
             TextFormField(
               decoration: const InputDecoration(
                 border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                 labelText: 'Введите название домена',
               ),
             ),
             TextButton(
               child: Text(name),
               onPressed: (){
                 //List<String> names = ['.md','.com','.ru','.org'];
                 if(x==0){
                   name = ".com";
                   x++;
                   restart();
                 }
                 else if(x==1){
                   name = ".ru";
                   x++;
                   restart();
                 }
                 else if(x==2){
                   name = ".org";
                   x++;
                   restart();
                 }
                 else if(x==3){
                   name = ".md";
                   x = 0;
                   restart();
                 }
               }

             ),
             TextButton(
                 child: Text(valute),
                 onPressed: (){
                    if(y==0){
                      valute = "EUR";
                      y++;
                      restart();
                    }
                    else if(y==1){
                      valute = "RUB";
                      y++;
                      restart();
                    }
                    else if(y==2){
                      valute = "USD";
                      y = 0;
                      restart();
                    }
                 }
             )
       ]
             )
             )
           ]
         )

       )
     );

 }
}
```

Comment: Если ответ правильный, отметьте его галочкой слева от текста ответа.

Answer (score 0):

#### О чем ошибка

Вставил код

получил следующее:

> An InputDecorator, which is typically created by a TextField, cannot have an unbounded width.
> This happens when the parent widget does not provide a finite width constraint. For example, if the InputDecorator is contained by a Row, then its width must be constrained. An Expanded widget or a SizedBox can be used to constrain the width of the InputDecorator or the TextField that contains it.
> 'package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart':
> Failed assertion: line 910 pos 7: 'layoutConstraints.maxWidth < double.infinity'

Там говориться о том, что `InputDecorator` не может иметь ограниченной ширины
И данный виджет не может использоваться вместе с родительскими элементами с неограниченной шириной. В частности там говориться о наиболее частом кейсе - использовании `InputDecorator` внутри `Row` который не ограничен по ширине.

Отсюда и ошибка.

Далее можно увидеть и ошибку рендеринга:

```
RenderObject: _RenderColoredBox#0bd33 relayoutBoundary=up2
  needs compositing
  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=null; fit=null (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=392.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: MISSING
```

Она также указывает на то, что размер не указан `size: MISSING`

#### Что с этим делать?

Одним из вариантов является обернуть все необходимые элементы виджетом `Expanded`
Задача данного виджета заполнять имеющееся в распоряжении пространство

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

```
Expanded(
    child: TextFormField(
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
            border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: 'Введите название домена',
        ),
    ))
```

Чтобы избежать вышеуказанных ошибок будет достаточно обернуть виджет в котором используется `InputDecoration()`

Однако, после использования Вы сразу столкнетесьс другой ошибкой, связанной с шириной.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Она(ширина) хоть будет и не бесконечная, но все равно будет выходить за рамки экрана.

Тут я сильно мудрить не стал и просто вставил два символа перехода строки(`\n`) в текст кнопки.
Ну и обернул их виджетом `Center` для выравнивания текста по центру

```
child: Center(
    child: Text(
        '$tick Зарегистрировать\nновый\nдомен',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
),
```

**Минимальный рабочий пример:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(ChooseDomain());
}

String name = ".md";
int x = 0;
String valute = "MDL";
int y = 0;
String tick = "❌";

class ChooseDomain extends StatelessWidget {
  void restart() => runApp(ChooseDomain());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Выберите домен'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            ),
            body: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                    TextButton(
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            '$tick Зарегистрировать\nновый\nдомен',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          tick = "✅";
                          restart();
                        }),
                    TextButton(
                        child: const Text('www.'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          String a = "NONE";
                        }),
                    Expanded(
                        child: TextFormField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Введите название домена',
                      ),
                    )),
                    TextButton(
                        child: Text(name),
                        onPressed: () {
                          //List<String> names = ['.md','.com','.ru','.org'];
                          if (x == 0) {
                            name = ".com";
                            x++;
                            restart();
                          } else if (x == 1) {
                            name = ".ru";
                            x++;
                            restart();
                          } else if (x == 2) {
                            name = ".org";
                            x++;
                            restart();
                          } else if (x == 3) {
                            name = ".md";
                            x = 0;
                            restart();
                          }
                        }),
                    TextButton(
                        child: Text(valute),
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (y == 0) {
                            valute = "EUR";
                            y++;
                            restart();
                          } else if (y == 1) {
                            valute = "RUB";
                            y++;
                            restart();
                          } else if (y == 2) {
                            valute = "USD";
                            y = 0;
                            restart();
                          }
                        })
                  ]))
            ])));
  }
}
```

И как итог

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну а по-хорошему все это нужно нормально сверстать не в одну строку а в несколько